# How to make fewer If statements?

Tags: javascript

I'm a super beginner programmer and I am making a simple app that chooses a monkey (gog) based on input for a high school project. I've looked up this question and all the answers seem to be case specific or go over my head so an ELI5 answer would be much appreciated. Here is my code for reference:

```js
    //variables
    var bananas;
    var color;
    var size;
    
    //updates color on click
    onEvent("colorDD", "click", function( ) {
      updateScreen();
    });
    
    //updates size on click
    onEvent("sizeDD", "click", function( ) {
      updateScreen();
    });
    
    //updates bananas consumed on slider move
    onEvent("bananaSlider", "mousemove", function( ) {
      updateScreen();
    });
    
    //Updates the screen with all info including bananas, color, and size to display Gog image
    
    function updateScreen() {
      
      //color storer
      color = getText("colorDD");
      
      //size storer
      size = getText("sizeDD");
        
      //banana storer
      bananas = getNumber("bananaSlider");
      
      
      //If statement for bottom text
      if (color == "Red" && bananas == 10 && size == "Big"){ // Big Red Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "Gog -1?!?!?!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog-1.gif");
      
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Big" && bananas < 5){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 720!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog720.gif");
      
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Big"){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 6!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog6.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Medium" && bananas > 6){ // Medium Red Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 51!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog51pog-min.gif");  
        
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Medium" && bananas < 4){ 
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 5!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog5.gif");  
        
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Medium"){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 33!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog33.gif");
      
        
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Small" && bananas > 6){ // Small Red Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 42!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog42-1.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Small" && bananas > 3){ 
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 51!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog51pog-min.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Red" && size == "Small"){ 
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 3!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog3.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Brown" && size == "Big" && bananas > 6){ // Big Brown Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 100!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog100-min.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Brown" && size == "Big" && bananas < 3){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 24!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog24.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Brown" && size == "Medium" && bananas < 5){ // Medium Brown Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 9!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog9.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Brown" && size == "Medium" && bananas > 7){ 
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 4!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog4.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Brown" && size == "Small" && bananas < 4){ // Small Brown Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Phone Gog!");
        setImageURL("gog", "phonegog.gif");
      
      } else if ( color == "Brown" && size == "Small" && bananas > 6){ 
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are gog 38!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog38.gif");
      
      } else if (color == "Brown" && bananas >= 5 ){ // Misc. Brown Gog
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 50!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog50.gif");
        
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Big" && bananas >= 9){ // Big Black Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 16!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog16.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Big" && bananas < 4){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 0!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog0.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Big"){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 14!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog14.gif");
          
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Medium" && bananas > 7){ // Medium Black Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 65!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog65-min.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Medium" && bananas < 4){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 3.5!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog3.5-min.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Small" && bananas < 4){ // Small Black Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 12!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog12-2.gif");
    
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Small" && bananas > 6){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 34!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog34.gif");
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" && size == "Small" ){
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 22!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog22.gif");
        
        
      } else if ( color == "Black" || bananas <5) { // Misc. Gogs
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 23!");
        setImageURL("gog", "gog23.gif");
        
      }  else if (bananas >5 && size != "Big") {
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 12!");   
        setImageURL("gog", "gog12.gif");
        
      } else {
        setText("feedbackOutput", "You are not a Gog yet!");// Default Gog
        setImageURL("gog", "gogprequil.gif");
        
      }
    
    }
```

As can be seen, there are three variables of bananas, color, and size and choosing certain values for each will give a different image on the screen.

Comment: What do these images look like?  If they're just different colors, you might be able to get away with a simple CSS filter!  Same with size.

Comment: In the generic sense, you can use an inverted `switch`/`case` statement, where you do something like `switch (true) { case (color === 'Red' && size === 'Small' && bananas > 3): doSomething(); break; }`, but it can probably be even simpler than that.

Comment: They are monkey GIFS so pretty complicated @Brad

Answer (score 2):

You can store the information in objects, then iterate through them and check:

```js
const gogs = [
    {color: "Red", size: "Big", cmp: "==", bananas: 10, fb: "Gog -1?!?!?!", img: "gog-1.gif"},
    {color: "Red", size: "Big", cmp: "<", bananas: 5, fb: "You are gog 720!", img: "gog720.gif"},
    {color: "Red", size: "Big", cmp: "none", fb: "You are Gog 6!", img: "gog6.gif"},
    {color: "Red", size: "Medium", cmp: ">", bananas: 5, fb: "You are Gog 51!", img: "gog51pog-min.gif"},
    // continue on like this
    // we need some special ones that can't be easily expressed
    {special: true, cond: (color, size, bananas) => color == "Black" || bananas < 5, fb: "You are Gog 23!", img: "gog23.gif"},
    {special: true, cond: (color, size, bananas) => bananas > 5 && size != "Big", fb: "You are Gog 12!", img: "gog12.gif"},
    {special: true, cond: () => true, fb: "You are not a Gog yet!", img: "gogprequil.gif"}
];

const cmps = {
    "=="(a, b) { return a == b; },
    ">"(a, b) { return a > b; },
    "<"(a, b) { return a < b; },
    ">="(a, b) { return a >= b; },
    "<="(a, b) { return a <= b; }
};

// later in your code when checking gogs
for (const gog of gogs) {
    if (gog.special) {
        if (!gog.cond(color, size, bananas)) {
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        if (gog.color != color || gog.size != size) {
            continue;
        }
        if (gog.cmp != "none" && !cmps[gog.cmp](bananas, gog.bananas)) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    setText("feedbackOutput", gog.fb);
    setImageURL("gog", gog.img);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to try to separate the data from the logic.  That simplifies updating the data, as well as working with the logic.  First, define your dataset:

```
const gogs = [
  { color: 'black', size: 'small', minBananas: 0, imgUrl: 'gog12-2.gif' },
  { color: 'black', size: 'small', minBananas: 6, imgUrl: 'gog34.gif' },
  // etc.
];
```

Now, when you want to do your data, you can do something like this:

```
const gog = gogs.find((gog) => {
  gog.color === color &&
  gog.size === size &&
  gog.miniBananas <= bananaCount
});

if (!gog) {
  return;
}

setImageURL(gog.imgUrl);
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

Like other folks are saying, you want to structure your data into Objects here, to handle all these weird mix of combinations.

Going on you'll also need to have ways to handle the edge cases/errors.

You can then call them dynamically by passing in any combination of values, so long as you keep them in the same order (like it seems like you're managing to do writing out all those different if/else mixes... good job asking a good question though, because wanting to minimize/avoid stuff like this shows you're definitely starting out on the right track)

```js
return {
  try {
    gif: gogs[size][color][bananaAmount()].gifUrl,
    msg: gogs[size][color][bananaAmount()].helperMsg
  }
  catch (error) {
    gif: null
    msg: `no gogs gif yet because: ${error}`
  }
}

function bananaAmount(counter) {
  switch (counter) {
    case (counter === 10) {
      return 'lotsBananas'
    }
    case (counter >= 6) {
      return 'someBananas'
    }
    case (counter <= 5 && counter !== 0) {
      return 'fewBananas'
    }
  }
}

const gogs = {
  big: {
    red: {
      lotsBananas: {
        gifUrl: 'filePath.gif'
        helperMsg: 'which gogs you are'
      }
      someBananas: {
        gifUrl: '...gif'
        // ...
      },
      fewBananas: {
        // ...
      }
    },
    black: {
      lotsBananas: {
        gifUrl: 'filePath.gif'
        helperMsg: 'which gogs you are'
      }
      someBananas: {
        gifUrl: '...gif'
      },
      fewBananas: {
        // ...
      }
    },
    brown: {
      ...
    }
  },
  medium: {
    ...
  },
  small: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of repetition of the `color` and `size` parameters. You can do what Aplet123 suggested, but it might not help you think about the general strategy of grouping if statements.

A simpler approach might be something like

```
    if (color == "Red") { // group by "Red" first--anything that is "Red" will go into this block
        if (size == "Big") { // next group by "Big" -- anything "Red" + "Big" will go into this block
            if (bananas == 10) { // so if we get true here, we know we are Red + Big + bananas = 10
                setText("feedbackOutput", "Gog -1?!?!?!");
                setImageURL("gog", "gog-1.gif");
            }
            else if (bananas < 5) { // if we get true here, we know we are Red + Big + bananas < 5
                setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 720!");
                setImageURL("gog", "gog720.gif");
            } 
            else {
                setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 6!");
                setImageURL("gog", "gog6.gif");
            } 
        } // end of block of conditions for "Big" + "Red"
        else if (size == "Medium" ) { // group by "Medium" 
            if (bananas > 6) {
                setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 51!");
                setImageURL("gog", "gog51pog-min.gif");  
        
            } 
            else if ( bananas < 4){ 
                setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 5!");
                setImageURL("gog", "gog5.gif");  
        
            } 
            else {
                setText("feedbackOutput", "You are Gog 33!");
                setImageURL("gog", "gog33.gif");
            }
      } // end of Red + Medium
      // next we would try the "Small" ones (left as an exercise to reader)
  }
  else if (color == "Brown") {
    // similar to above, group by sizes then for each size check banana conditions
  }
 // etc
```

This doesn't save on length at all, but it saves on the complexity of each `if` statement, which is probably what a beginner should be thinking about.